# Does iOS MultipeerConnectivity provide routing layer?

Tags: ios, networking, routes, wifi, distributed

I am writing an app that is suppose to work without a connection to mobile carrier and without local WiFi. Each device will act as transmitter, receiver **and router**. 
My main challenge so far is that I cannot figure out how exactly [MultipeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/) works as documentation on MC is really limited. Apple denied revealing technical specification of MC claiming it's a proprietary network stack, so I have to rely on network sniffers and [reverse-engineering](https://datatheorem.github.io/documents/BH_MultipeerConnectivity.pdf) which is not the quickest way to figure out how MC works.

Suppose I have 100 devices forming a mesh network in such way that **each device is within the range of at least one other device and at maximum three other devices**.

Is there any way to send a message from node A to node B that is *not* within the range of node A without the need to broadcast the message to all other nodes? I mean that message should be properly routed through all other nodes.
Does MC include a routing layer too or I have to write it myself?

From what I can see *ad hoc delay tolerant wireless networks* is still a hot subject in research.
These slides on [ad hoc delay tolerant wireless network](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jac22/talks/sta/talks/dtn-history.pdf) shed more light on the subject as it was a few years ago. And [also this paper](https://www.ijedr.org/papers/IJEDR1504145.pdf). Has Apple progressed it much with MC? 
I cannot really see any way to send a message between nodes not directly connected to each other without flooding.
Correct?
[image: Mesh network]

Comment: This is quite interesting! I highly doubt that there is a way to send a message from node A to node B without having routing table. Since two devices only rely on sending messages on mesh network, I believe it means there is supposed to be some sort of routing mechanism to figure out how to send a message through mesh network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`MCSession` Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionClassRef/index.html) states that

> Sessions currently support up to 8 peers, including the local peer.

Also, the overview you cited says

> In the discovery phase, your app uses a browser object […] to browse for nearby peers[.]

Moreover, [the documentation on managing peers manually](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCSessionClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013322-CH1-SW5) suggests that all peers in a session must be connected with each other to have them in a session.

This is suggesting that the framework only covers the communication between **nearby** devices, as in 'reachable by bluetooth or WiFi'. Naturally, those devices do not need complex routing, as they do communicate with each other and the benefit of the framework is simple multicasting between nearby devices, from a programmers' point of view.

As far as your question goes, this is about it - trivially, since all peers an a `MCSession` have links to each other - there is no routing needed.

This does however, allow you to construct a routing layer pretty easy.

Given your scenario, there will be multiple `MCSession`s with devices being part of at least one. All devices that are part of more than one `MCSession` do become routers and interconnect the `MCSession`s with each other.

The rest of the task should be straight forward; defining a namespace for addressing devices and implementing a routing protocol of your choice.

The old days of the internet, with unstable dialup connections, might be a plus factor for you as the routing protocols in place are rather stable in regards of link loss.

Here are two good starting points for you to make your choice of better fit:

- [Link state routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_routing_protocol)
- [Distance vector routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol)

Comment: Thanks for the answer